# How to chain multiple middleware handlers with a route handler?

Tags: go

I'm working on a API using the **net/http** package. A basic endpoint makes use of a higher order function and looks like this

```
func handleRoute( /* params */ ) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Calling route handler")

        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    }
}
```

My middleware handlers almost look the same

```
type Middleware func(http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc

func fooMiddleware( /* params */ ) Middleware {
    return func(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
        return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Println("Calling foo middleware before next handler")

            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)

            fmt.Println("Calling foo middleware after next handler")
        }
    }
}

// Implementation for barMiddleware goes here...
```

Using it this way makes it possible to register a new route by chaining the middleware handlers

```
func createRoute(handleRoute http.HandlerFunc, middlewares ...Middleware) http.HandlerFunc {
    // we need a reverse loop to ensure the expected call order
    for i := len(middlewares) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        middleware := middlewares[i]
        handleRoute = middleware(handleRoute)
    }

    return handleRoute
}
```

*Example usage:*

```
mux.HandleFunc("GET /something", createRoute(handleRoute( /* params */ ), fooMiddleware( /* params */ ), barMiddleware( /* params */ )))
```

*Example output:*

```
Calling foo middleware before next handler
Calling bar middleware before next handler
Calling route handler
Calling bar middleware after next handler
Calling foo middleware after next handler
```

It would be awesome to change the **createRoute** function so it only accepts a number of handler functions where the actual route handler must be the last one.

So consumers could setup a "fluent" route

*Example usage:*

> createRoute(middleware1(...params...), middleware2(...params...), ..., routeHandler(...params...))

I wasn't able to find a solution for this since middleware handlers and route handlers do not share the same signature ( since middleware handlers expect a "next" handler )

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually want to keep the middleware signature instead of the route handler signature in the parameter list for `createRoute`. There are several tricks you can employ.

1. Use the handler as the first argument:

```
createRoute(handler http.Handler, mw ...Middleware) {...}
```

2. Instead of `createRoute`, use `createMiddleware`:

```
func createMiddleware(mw ...Middleware) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
   return func(hnd http.Handler) http.Handler {
       next:=hnd
       for k:=len(mw)-1;k>=0;k-- {
          next=mw(next)
       }
       return next
   }
}
```

This way you can create a route:

```
createMiddleware(mw1,mw2,mw3)(handler)
```

Also works for:

```
createMiddleware()(handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try and wrapping the route handler into a middleware-like signature and then applying your middleware chaining logic. That way, all handlers can be treated uniformly as middleware until the actual route handler is executed.

First, make sure your middleware and route handlers can be processed in the same way by adjusting their definitions slightly.
Then create a unified type that can represent both middleware and the final route handler. Since middleware functions expect a "next" handler to call, and route handlers do not, you can wrap the route handler to match the middleware signature.
That way, you can implement a chaining function that treats the last handler differently, wrapping it to match the middleware signature.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

// Middleware type remains as before.
type Middleware func(http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc

// Handler type for both middleware and route handlers.
type Handler func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)

// Adjusted wrapRouteHandler to potentially include a call to "next" middleware or route handler.
func wrapRouteHandler(routeHandler Handler, next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        routeHandler(w, r) // Execute the current handler.
        // If a next handler exists, it is called here.
        if next != nil {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        }
    }
}

// Chain middleware and include "next" calls.
func createRoute(handlers ...Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    // Start with an empty finalHandler that serves as a placeholder for the chain's end.
    var finalHandler http.HandlerFunc = func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}

    // Chain the handlers in reverse order, wrapping each one and including the "next" handler in the sequence.
    for i := len(handlers) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        // For the last handler, next is initially nil.
        next := finalHandler
        // Wrap the current handler to include a call to the "next" handler.
        finalHandler = wrapRouteHandler(handlers[i], next)
    }

    return finalHandler
}

func main() {
    // Example usage
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/something", createRoute(
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { fmt.Println("Middleware 1") },
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { fmt.Println("Middleware 2") },
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { // Actual route handler
            fmt.Println("Route handler")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        },
    ))

    // Start server (error handling omitted for brevity)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}
```

The actual route handler is indeed the last one in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `createRoute` function as below.

- `createRoute` function.

```golang
func createRoute(handlers ...http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    if len(handlers) == 0 {
        return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            fmt.Println("No any handler configured")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    }

    rootHandler := handlers[len(handlers)-1]
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        custom := &CustomResponseWriter{ResponseWriter: w}
        for i := 0; i <= len(handlers)-2; i++ {
            handlers[i].ServeHTTP(custom, r)
            // If status code is not in the 2xx range, exit early.
            if custom.statusCode != 0 && (custom.statusCode < 200 || custom.statusCode >= 300) {
                return
            }
        }
        rootHandler.ServeHTTP(custom, r)
    }
}
```

- `customResponseWriter` a wrapper to the `http.ResponseWriter` that keeps track of the status code written to the response.

```golang
type CustomResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    statusCode int
}


func (r *CustomResponseWriter) Header() http.Header {
    return r.ResponseWriter.Header()
}


func (r *CustomResponseWriter) Write(data []byte) (int, error) {
    return r.ResponseWriter.Write(data)
}


func (r *CustomResponseWriter) WriteHeader(statusCode int) {
    r.statusCode = statusCode
    r.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(statusCode)
}
```

**Example:**

- *Example usage:* `createRoute(foo(), boo(), routeHandler())`

Middlewares

```golang
func foo(/* params */) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Calling foo middleware handler")
    }
}
```

```golang
func boo(/* params */) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Calling boo middleware handler")
    }
}
```

Route Handler

```golang
// routeHandler is the route handler that executes after all middleware handlers.
func routeHandler(/* params */) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Calling route handler")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks complicated :S Spinning up a custom `func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` with a custom implementation of `CustomResponseWriter` and `handlers[i].ServeHTTP(custom, r)` feels overengieered

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in go because variadic argument should be the last argument in the function's signature (check **Function types** section of [go language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec)).

But your use case may be solved by a custom router (or using the existing one like [chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi)) with some support for groups. So middlewares would be assigned to the group, and handlers would be defined within a group.

Alternatively, you may split the responsibility and introduce additional `struct` which will take care of the middlewares and would provide the way to wrap you handler.

### Examples with chi:

```golang
r := chi.NewRouter()
r.Group(func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Use(middleware1, middleware2, middleware3)
    r.Get("/something", createHandler(handlerParams))
})
```

or with path prefix instead of group:

```golang
r := chi.NewRouter()
r.Route("/prefix", func(r chi.Router) {
    r.Use(middleware1, middleware2, middleware3)
    r.Get("/path", createHandler(handlerParams))
})
```

### Examples with middleware chain:

The chain itself:

```golang
type Middleware func(http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc

type MiddlewareChain struct {
    middleware []Middleware
}

func NewMiddlewareChain(middleware ...Middleware) MiddlewareChain {
    return MiddlewareChain{middleware: middleware}
}

func (c MiddlewareChain) Wrap(handler http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    for i := len(c.middleware) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        middleware := c.middleware[i]
        handler = middleware(handler)
    }
    return handler
}
```

And then use it almost the way you was asking for:

```golang
chain := NewMiddlewareChain(fooMiddleware(), barMiddleware())
mux.HanleFunc("GET /something", chain.Wrap(handler1))
mux.HanleFunc("GET /else", chain.Wrap(handler2))
```